# MSSQL server 2008 R2, Default user permission

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, permissions

For MSSQL server 2008 R2, how can fall back permissions be set?

In my database, I have n user roles and m schemas where each role has only access to a few of the m schemas (assume for simpilicity, the roles are not owner of the schemas).

I have understood that 'public' is the default role that cannot be revoked. In addition, denying permissions on 'public' could not be revoked on lower levels, an 'pulic' overrules any contrasting GRANT permissions.

As a consequence, public is not very useful as a fall back role where denys should be the set, e.g. by default users should be denied SELECTs. If I am right, this means that I would have to set permissions explicitly for each of the n roles and m schemas. Adding a new schema, requires defining the permissions for the new schema for each role a new (n times you have to repeat the same permission definitions).

So my question: Is there any way to define a fall-back role that users would have (incl. denys) that need not be explictly assigned to the role (similar to 'public') and that would become relevant if no rights are specified?

In my example above, this could mean: The default is deny SELECTs on all schemas if not specified otherwise. When I create a new schema, unless permission is explicitly granted, the existing n users do not have access. In only grant permission explicitly for one role and leave the others.

Comment: Are you looking for a second default role? Something that would default instead of public? Not really sure what it is you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: I try to have a design that supports that for a new role only for the relevant schemas permissions must be set while other schemas can be ignored. Also a new schema would not require to define permissions for each existing role. I consider such a solution much more robust and secure.

Comment: By default, users have no object permissions except the very limited permissions inherited from public role membership. User permissions are cumulative from all role memberships with DENY taking precedence over GRANT. I suggest you avoid granting permissions to public or directly to users, and avoid DENY entirely. A user will then have only permissions via user role membership.

Comment: That does not answer the question: How can I deny a permission implicitly but explicitly grant it? If I have understood correctly, the design seems to allow only a pretty inefficient approach. It's like having a door where everyone has a key unless you explicitly take away the key from the person while, what I am after is an approach where nobody has a key unless I explicitly give it to him.